# Function checking out of bounds/segmentation fault in 2D loop

Tags: c++, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm looping through a 2D array of Cell objects and checking each object's surrounding Cells. Before checking each cell, I need to make sure it exists within the array. To do so I'm using the following function:

```
bool Cell::isInBounds(int h, int w) {
    if ((h >= 0 && w >= 0) || (h < HEIGHT && w < WIDTH)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems to be returning true when it shouldn't, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious. `i` and `h` are being passed, for example, as `cell[i+1][j+1].isInBounds((i+1), (j+1))`.

New to C++. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
 if ((h >= 0 && w >= 0) && (h < HEIGHT && w < WIDTH)) {
```

Comment: Drrp...can't believe I missed that. Thanks.